# What is the typed output of the Yarg() function?

Tags: typescript, yargs

I've been making a CLI and i needed yargs for parsing my arguments in a nice way. I am using typescript and i don't know the output of this Function, didn't find it anywhere as well:

```js
const argv = Yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .command('serve', 'Start the Bots.', (yargs: Argv) => {
    return yargs.option('bots', {
      alias: 'b',
      describe: 'Number of bots to create',
      type: 'number',
      default: 10,
      demand: 'Amount is required!',
    });
  })
  .parse();
```

Setting the `argv` to `any` is not a option. I guess extending from the base interface like this:

```js
interface yargs_config extends Yargs.Argv<{}> {
  bots: number;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it installed with typings: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/tree/main/lib/typings

Comment: The class definition: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/561fc7a787228b226e0ba76ab674456cbd30cd37/lib/yargs-factory.ts#L164

Comment: `parse` returns `Arguments | Promise<Arguments>`: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/561fc7a787228b226e0ba76ab674456cbd30cd37/lib/yargs-factory.ts#L1072

Answer (score -1):

The Type casting at the end fixed my Problem thanks @Thomas Sablik

```js
interface BotArguments extends Arguments {
  bots: number;
}

const botService = new BotService();
const argv = await Yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .command('serve', 'Start the Bots.', (yargs: Argv) => {
    return yargs.option('bots', {
      alias: 'b',
      describe: 'Number of bots to create',
      type: 'number',
      default: 10,
      demand: 'Amount is required!',
    });
  })
  .parse();
const bots = (argv as BotArguments).bots;
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the question: _What is the typed output of the Yarg() function?_

Comment: @jauki, try to answer the question you posted, that might help others with the same problem.